# Get Facebook user basic info without authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to be able to show a user which of their friends have signed up for the app as soon as they come to the site, before they are authorized, as long as they are logged into Facebook in the current browser.

Is this request possible? I have definitely seen this sort of thing, but I am not sure if this is universally available. I recall seeing some info on this topic on Stackoverflow, but cannot find it at the moment.

It's a Ruby on Rails app and I have been using Koala to make the authorized requests.

Thanks.

Comment: No, that is not possible via API, because you don’t get _any_ details about a visiting user before they connect to your app. You can only use what the social plugins are offering, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

Comment: Okay thanks. That's all I needed to know. One of these plugins should generally do the trick.